# Unity only render objects from a layer inside a 2D mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I'm trying to make a 2D top down game with a field of view.

My field of view is shown by a 2D mesh of the fov, not being able to pass through walls.

I need to be able to put some objects such as enemies in a layer that's only rendered when it's inside the view cone.

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSeUMTaNFYk&t=1126s) tutorial but couldn't find the overwrite setting shown at 18:16 (I believe this is because the LWRP no longer exists in Unity). Are there any alternatives or other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to implement it from scratch and WITH BUILT-IN RENDER PIPELINE, you can read along :

lets say this is the scene , the white plane is fov and cubes are enemies:
[image]

the fov can have a simple shader. very simple shader. this for example:

```
Shader "Unlit/simple_shader"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                return 1;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll need a seperate camera to render ONLY the fov mesh and save it as an image, which we know as RenderTexture. which will look like a black and white mask:
[image]

then make another camera layer that only renders enemies:
[image]

then add the generated mask to it:
[image]

then put it on top of the main camera:
[image]

- here is the sample asset I exported along with the scene:
  https://usaupload.com/shared/hkcayffn-9psb5e_loknmu3086nnh2--tbk0fm5s8xqj8ilnyok2zklav8-4mk7i8tf1tsjfbstgzrpw3upwi_w2e96k9nqm05-knhk3m_1237myy8nvco910c67afmo

Answer (score 3):

The concept of using Layer-wise render passes and the stencil buffer is basically still the same also in [URP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@11.0/manual) (the replacement for LWRP).

The asset to configure this should by default be in

```
 Assets/UniversalRenderPipelineAsset_Renderer
```

Also see [See Through Objects with Stencil Buffers using Unity URP](https://theslidefactory.com/see-through-objects-with-stencil-buffers-using-unity-urp/) which explains it pretty good.

---

Or if you use the built-in render pipeline you would need shaders that directly implement this via a [Stencil](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) pass or subshader.

---

As an alternative you can also use the `DepthTexture`. For some examples using that and the ShaderGraph checkout [Creating Overlap Shader Effects, Such as Underwater and Night Vision, in Unity's Shader Graph](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/creating-overlap-underwater-night-vision-effects-in-shader-graph).

Answer (score 1):

The solution used in your tutorial is to have a shader using the stencil buffer to only show the part of the enemies that stands inside your FOV mesh.

This solution a quite possible in any Render Pipeline

Hope that helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using 2019.3 URP or later, you need to change the FieldOfView shader type to Universal Render Pipeline/Simple Lit.  It has the same Render Face functions as the shader from the video.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/simple-lit-shader.html